# Bash shell exploit using SIP

Tags: wireshark, shellshock, bash, sip

I have a SIP proxy server, that would like to test Shellshock on.

I have used this https://github.com/zaf/sipshock to try and test.

but this is what I get[image: SIPtest].

So I just want to know generally what is the flow like for this exploit over sip ( anyone with a wireshark capture)

Can any one help to interpret what the above output means.

Comment: Is your SIP server listening on port 5060?